# Angular ui -router Page browser Refresh Showing null values ?How could persist the data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I am using Angular Js Ui router, when click the button, i have call the function and take over the params and calling the service and getting a results from Db. working good.

In the point of time.

When Browser refresh the page, the value gets null and respone get 500 error.

It looks into State configuration path and go to the controller,there have null values.
How could persist the data in ui-state provider.

```
Url Look like :
http://localhost/Myproject/#/home/Retailer/retailerId=1?retailerCode=3

When I click the button i have carry over the value
 $state.go('Home.retailer', { 'retailerId': $scope.param1, 'retailercode': $scope.param1});



While refersh the page, the values getting null in module.

.state('home.retailer', {

        url: '/contract/:retailerId:9?retailercode:1',
        params:{
                   'retailerId': '9', 'retailercode': '1' 
       },
        views: {
            '@': {
                templateUrl: baseUrl + 'retailr/retailerList',
                controller: 'home',
            }
        },
        data: {
           Name: '',
            Img: 'Images/1.png'
        }

    })
```

Note:
When button click i have get the value , so service will return the data.

Problem:
when refresh the page, it goes into module and check the home.retailer , and back to the service. how could  to persist the data when refresh the browser.

what exactly this could do:  params:{
                       'retailerId': '9', 'retailercode': '1' 
           },

```
Because of null, response Here I am passing the retailer id and Retailer code in service inside the controller. 
 `RetailerService.pageLoad($scope.retailerId,$scope.retailercode)` when Click the button ,
RetailerService.pageLoad($scope.retailerId :9 ,$scope.retailercode :1) , 



Page Refresh RetailerService.pageLoad($scope.retailerId : null,$scope.retailercode : null)`
```

Comment: We need the controllers and the db's service. Furthermore You put a **H** in `$state.go('Home...` when your state is named **home...**

Comment: @Walfrat, this is sample code , the problem arise becuse of null values in two fields,retailerId': '9', 'retailercode': '1' . i need to persist the data when  browse refresh the page.

Comment: And how are we supposed to answer when we don't know how `$scope.param1` get is value assigned ? Give us the full controller that goes along with the `$state.go`

Comment: Working Fine.

@walfrat : Dont confuse the Question. I have a home page , there have button  when i click the data it goes into nested views, and i have the vaue Retaiilerid 9 and retailer code :1.


Problem:
Now I am in Retailer page, there is no event , i am outside the DoM.

Browser page Refresh happens, not getting  a value in  Retailer code and retailer Id


It not goes into controller directly, it will goes into app and search the routing, match the routing,


Service Expect a value , but not get a value

Comment: but the value is supposed to be in the URI rights ? SO you should be able to not get null values.Are you sure this URL is properly written ? `'/contract/:retailerId:9?retailercode:1'`

Comment: tats the problem, i am getting null , when i have set the params , and set it in url also.

Comment: i think your URL config is wrong, can you try this : `'/contract/:retailerId/:retailercode`. It may not be what you want (default value) but just try it first to check if it works

Comment: assume  you have url, in url page refresh happens, you have to get the value in controller, in controller by using that value pass in factory or service get the data how you do

Comment: is there any way to get a  carry a value and pass in controller.

Comment: @walfrat  , if i hardcode  the value in rootscope  in the controller , return the results.now i have manually given the value in controller scope  means return the result . Are you Sure can  i get the value from State Url to Controller scope or rootscope?this is my confusion or else i have store in browser storages?

Comment: If the value is in the URL and has been define in the state configuration, you can get it by injecting `$stateParams` into your controller

Comment: @walfrat, thanks ,This is what i need , var RetailerController = function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $stateParams)

{

$scope.retailerId = $stateParams.retailerId;
}

Where i have set in Url?

In Params : params:{
                   'retailerId': '9', 'retailercode': '1' 
       },

or


In Url:

url: '/contract/:retailerId:9?retailercode:1',

Comment: i don't really know what you're trying to do there. Can you try the following : remove the attribute params in the sate and set the url like this : `'/contract/:retailerId/:retailercode`. Tell me if that is working first, then we will try to see if we can improve it to match more to what you need.

Answer (score 4):

To persist data on refresh you will need to store it in browser storage.  Here is a good example of a factory using localStorage.

```
app.factory("storageFactory", function($window) {
  return {
    setData: function(val) {
      $window.localStorage && $window.localStorage.setItem('my-storage', val);
      return this;
    },
    getData: function() {
      return $window.localStorage && $window.localStorage.getItem('my-storage');
    }
  };
});
```

So you will set data at various times in your controller, and then call get data on page load to ensure any pre-set vars are captured.

Edit: As mentioned below instead of localStorage, sessionStorage is also an option.  What you choose should be dependent on your needs.

Comment: One comment on this is not to use local storage but instead use session storage. Local will persist across sessions and browsers which may not be preferred. Session will destroy when the browser is closed. Another option if you don't want to use session is to setup a factory service to store the data in scope

Comment: Is there any other way without storing in session ,cookies, and local storage. can i pass into params and getting the value in service

Comment: If you want to keep data that are not part of the URI in any way, you'll need local storage or session, refresh = loss of all javascript context.

Comment: Very true sessionStorage can be used as well. What the developer chooses should be specific to their use case.

Comment: Because its not a static one,its dynamic one may be now i am in retailer code 10, there have lots of records in db. In UI page refresh happens, if i am storing every id in localstorage is not a good thing

Comment: You can structure your code to only persist to browser storage when it makes sense.  You don't have to do it every single time the var changes.  Just call the setData method only when needed.